# Directory extension attribute on-premise to be included in core claim coming in token

Tags: azure, directory, azure-active-directory

Trying to synchronize Custom on-premise attribute to Azure Active directory which is further used by web app hosted in azure.
Note : Not using Azure AD B2C

The authentication token coming in web app has claims but does not have the custom attribute part of it.

I am able to get the custom attribute using graph API but want to understand if there is a way to get the directory extension attribute in the core claim itself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using Azure AD's [claims mapping feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-claims-mapping). When you configure your claims mapping policy, you would use a `ClaimsSchema` like the following:

```
{
    "Source":"user",
    "ExtensionID":"extension_{appId}_myExtensionProperty",
    "DisplayName":"My Extension Property",
    "SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/extension_{appId}_myExtensionProperty",
    "JwtClaimType":"extension_{appId}_myExtensionProperty"
},
```

For JWT tokens, be wary not to over-do the claim customizations, or you may run into token size issues.